# Sed not replacing text correctly

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm trying to run sed to replace some text in a file and I've broken the text apart, ran sed on it individually to make sure everything is escaped correctly and it works. When I put it all back together it doesn't change anything. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

This is the command I'm running

```
sed -i -e 's/"php"   => \x27\x27,/"php"   => \x27\/opt\/remi\/php70\/root\/usr\/sbin\/php-fpm\x27,/g'
```

It's supposed to change

```
"php"   => '',
```

to

```
"php"   => '/opt/remi/php70/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm',
```

I figured it might have something to do with white space due to how the code is indented or something in which I tried a couple things but I'm not getting anywhere.

It's in a block that looks like this:

```
    $pathToExternals = array(
            "php"   => '',                  // Something like /usr/bin/php. If empty, will be found in PATH.
            "curl"  => '',                  // Something like /usr/bin/curl. If empty, will be found in PATH.
            "gzip"  => '',                  // Something like /usr/bin/gzip. If empty, will be found in PATH.
            "id"    => '',                  // Something like /usr/bin/id. If empty, will be found in PATH.
            "stat"  => '',                  // Something like /usr/bin/stat. If empty, will be found in PATH.
    );
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Which part of this is the data being processed?

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure what you're asking, can you please clarify?

As far as I'm aware it's simply supposed to replace all instances of the text specified to what I specify, correct?

Comment: Yes, but in reading your question it is not clear what you are processing.

Comment: I'm processing text manipulation with sed to change
`"php"   => '',`
to
`"php"   => '/opt/remi/php70/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm',`

in a file (config.php)

I simply want that text to be appended and changed to include the file path to php

Comment: It works for me as is.  What is your actual output and how does it vary from what you want?

Comment: The best way to show you would be some pics:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ftVh3X6eQAiXnhjr_Neta4Auaf8EFv-d

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1i8OHOkAmjxZTumqXVRfhXI6i9Z25J7th

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TaZVAkEvTpquYRRPxsNq4UkUUJJ1Jqdp

Comment: @Zac1989 Try `sed -i -e 's/"php"[[:space:]]*=>[[:space:]]*\x27\x27,/"php"   => \x27\/opt\/remi\/php70\/root\/usr\/sbin\/php-fpm\x27,/g'`

Comment: That worked! So it was due to the white space in between `"php"` and `=>`?

Comment: @Zac1989 Yes, `sed` as a programming language permits the use of whitespace for readability. I believe this applies to what's inside `s///` as well as outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your source file may have some tabs in it while the sed command assumed only blanks.  To do the replacement regardless of whether the white space consists of blanks or tabs, try:

```
sed -i -e 's/"php"[[:space:]]*=>[[:space:]]*\x27\x27,/"php" => \x27\/opt\/remi\/php70\/root\/usr\/sbin\/php-fpm\x27,/g'
```

`[[:space:]]*` matches zero or more of any white space character.

As [alhadis](https://superuser.com/users/403378/alhadis) points out, we can avoid the need to escape `/` if we use a different delimiter for the substitute command.  For example, we can choose `|`:

```
sed  -e 's|"php"[[:space:]]*=>[[:space:]]*\x27\x27,|"php"   => \x27/opt/remi/php70/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm\x27,|g'
```

Comment: I also recommend using a different delimiter when matching/inserting pathnames, to avoid the nasty `\/learning\/toothpick\/syndrome`. E.g.,: `s~match~/foo/bar/baz~g`

Comment: I will definitely look into that, this regex stuff is very new to me, thank you.

Comment: @Zac1989 The first few sections of this page are an excellent way to ease yourself into regex: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Comment: @Alhadis Good suggestion.  I added it to the answer.  Also, Zac1989, I second the recommendation of the Grymoire tutorial.  Grymoire tutorials can be a bit out-of-date but they do provide a good concise introduction.

Comment: @John1024 Perhaps recommend `[[:blank:]]` instead of `[[:space:]]` if horizontal whitespace (tab or space) is to be matched. The latter will also include form-feeds and newlines (I know `sed` processes records line-by-line, but I'm sure how universal this is). Either way, it's worth noting the difference between the two classes. =)